# Why does weaker local gravity cause lower sea level?

Tags: geophysics, oceanography, sea-level, gravity, ocean-models

The weaker local gravity in the [Indian Ocean geoid low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_Geoid_Low) (IOGL) causes the sea level to be 106 m below the [global mean sea level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_mean_sea_level). Why is that ?

> *"Because of this lower density, the gravitational pull in the IOGL
> region is weaker than normal."* [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_Geoid_Low)

I would have expected the exact opposite: namely that **stronger** (not weaker) gravitational pull would pull the water down **stronger** and therefore cause a lower sea level. What is wrong with my logic ?

[image: earth gravitational model]

Comment: Note that this question has been asked before, but with no upvoted answer: [Why is sealevel higher where gravity is higher](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/25259/why-is-sealevel-higher-where-gravity-is-higher/25271)?

Comment: It's also been asked (and answered!) at Physics.SE https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/773380